# updating Json object

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a json object that I need to update. The original object is a list that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "firstName":"Jane",
    "lastName":"Smith"
  },
  {
    "firstName":"Jack",
    "lastName":"Brown"
  }
]
```

For each element in the list, we have an extra field, "age", that needs to be added at run-time, so the result should look like the following:

```
[
  {
    "firstName":"Jane",
    "lastName":"Smith",
    "age": "21"
  },
  {
    "firstName":"Jack",
    "lastName":"Brown",
    "age": "34"
  }
]
```

Any suggestions how to do this so the result is still json?

Thanks.

Comment: How should you determine what age to add to what object?

Comment: @LimbSoup I will get them at run-time. The example is purposely simplified. All I need to know is how to de-construct th eoriginal Json and the re-construct it again with an extra field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommended deserializing the JSON array you receive into a `List` of case classes, then having some function fill in the missing attributes based on the current attributes of the case class, and finally serializing them as JSON and serving the response.

Let's make a `Person` case class with the fields that will be missing as `Option`:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Option[Int])

object Person {
    implicit val format: Format[Person] = Json.format[Person]

    def addAge(person: Person): Person = {
        val age = ... // however you determine the age
        person.copy(age = Some(age))
    }
}
```

Within the companion object for `Person` I've also defined a JSON serializer/deserializer using the `format` macro, and a stub for a function that will find a person's age then copy it back into the `person` and return it.

Deep within the web service call you might then have something like this:

```
val jsArray = ... // The JsValue from somewhere

jsArray.validate[List[Person]].fold(
    // Handle the case for invalid incoming JSON
    error => InternalServerError("Received invalid JSON response from remote service."),
    // Handle a deserialized array of List[Person]
    people => {
        Ok(
            // Serialize as JSON, requires the implicit `format` defined earlier.
            Json.toJson(
                // Map each Person to themselves, adding the age
                people.map(person => Person.addAge(person))
            )
        )
    }
)
```

This method is much safer, otherwise you'll have to extract values from the array one by one and concatenate objects, which is very awkward. This will also allow you to easily handle errors when the JSON you receive is missing fields you're expecting.

Comment: I believe this solves my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.body.asJson.map {
  jm => (jm.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("age" -> 123))
}
```

Comment: My json value originates from a response, not a request. Response.body.asJson or response.json.map does not compile, of course...

Comment: What/where is the origin of the JSON? Is it the result of calling a webservice (`play.api.libs.ws.WS`) or unmarshalled from other objects etc.?

Comment: @user3777482 : from wherever your json comes in, has no impact in how you update the json. To update json this is what you need `(jm.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("age" -> 123))` as described in my answer

Comment: @Vikas Pandya -  My Json is a JsValue but not a JsObject, so the code throws a run-time error.

Comment: @Donovan Muller - Yes, my code is the result of calling a webservice.